# MongoEngine fieldDoesNotExist error but it actually is

Tags: python, mongodb, error-handling, mongoengine

I have a class:

```
class POI(Document):
    location = PointField(required=True)
    name = StringField(default='')
    generate_by = IntField(required=True)
    status = StringField(default='Active')
    colleсted_by = IntField()
    time_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

When i try to insert

```
POI(location=[55.430212, 30.521000], generate_by=1241254, name="Sample", collected_by=None)
```

the error occured

```
mongoengine.errors.FieldDoesNotExist: The fields "{'collected_by'}" do not exist on the document "POI"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Collected_by is int field and u r passing string "NONE" In it

Answer (score 5):

You actually have a tiny typo in the two "collected_by" strings which makes them different, for some reason the "c" you are using here:

```
class POI(Document):
    location = PointField(required=True)
    name = StringField(default='')
    generate_by = IntField(required=True)
    status = StringField(default='Active')
    colleсted_by = IntField()
         ^
         |
```

is not the regular Latin "c" but a Cyrillic character that looks exactly like the latin "c".

In fact:

- latin "c" (https://www.codetable.net/decimal/99)
- cyrillic "с" (https://www.codetable.net/decimal/1089)

See below:

```
In [16]: "collected_by" == "colleсted_by"
Out[16]: False

In [17]: "с" == "c"
Out[17]: False

In [20]: ord("с"), ord("c")
Out[20]: (1089, 99)
```

If you make them the same, the code will work like a charm

Comment: Wow! This did not solve my problem, but I am upvoting you just because you figured this out. Kudos!